# Tensorflow doesn't work. And do not have any error code

Tags: python, tensorflow

Cause I'm Korean, there are some Koream messages. When I import tensorflow, the below error messages occur.

But I can't find any error code in it.

```
import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-23-a649b509054f>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow

  File "C:\Users\TaeyongLee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *

  File "C:\Users\TaeyongLee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

  File "C:\Users\TaeyongLee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TaeyongLee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\TaeyongLee\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 648, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: 지정된 모듈을 찾을 수 없습니다.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TaeyongLee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\TaeyongLee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\TaeyongLee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\TaeyongLee\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

cf) 지정된 모듈을 찾을 수 없습니다. means roughly "No module that you find."

please help me.

Comment: A `DLL` is missing. Check the missing file with `dependency walker` and install the required DLL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you follow the instructions in [Create the pip package and install?](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/#create-the-pip-package-and-install).

This step is necessary for your default Python installation to be able to import tensorflow.

Please use this [Github Issue Tracker](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2120) to get this issue solved.

To get this issue solved 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'. Please check this [Tensorflow Issue Tracker](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10033).

For any quick reference of tensorflow issues with python. Please use this [Issue Tracker](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues).

Comment: Thank you for references. But I follow all instructions on first site.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, this is due to missing DLLs (or missing paths thereto). You can use [this script](https://gist.github.com/mrry/ee5dbcfdd045fa48a27d56664411d41c) to figure out which one.